# Qual é a diferença entre axios e fetch no Javscript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Olá, estou estudando fetch e axios na parte de promises do javascript. Existe alguma diferença entre os dois além da compatibilidade? Algum deles dá mais ou menos performance ou pode ser mais eficiente em determinada situação?
Vi que o axios passa os dados via xhr que era um método mais antigo de pegar dados.

Comment: Bom, provavelmente alguém dará uma resposta mais elaborada, mas há uma grande diferença entre os dois, o **fetch** é nativo do `JavaScript` enquanto o **axios** é uma biblioteca que precisa ser instalada ou utilizada como CDN, isso por si só já diz muito não?!

Comment: @LeAndrade nativo do JS?? Voce quiz dizer nativo de várias plataformas que dão suporte ao JS (navegadores e mais recentemente o Node.js), não?

Comment: @CmteCardeal isso mesmo, não quis me referir a quem implantou, mas sim ao fato de se abrir o console no browser e digitar fetch o comando será reconhecido (nos navegadores que dão suporte) e o axios por ser uma biblioteca externa não.